# Python lyric opener works for one file but not for the other?

Tags: python, file, printing, python-3.x

I've coded a program which helps me to quickly toggle between lyrics of songs. It reads the lyrics from `.lyr` file and prints them out to me.

Here's a simplified version, without any additional features like `edit_line()`. The problem still appears with this code.

```
import os

class Lyrics:

    def __init__(self, file):
        '''Initialize new Lyrics object'''
        self.file = file.replace("/", "\\")
        self.path = self.file.rsplit("\\", 1)[0] + "\\"
        self.suffix = "." + self.file.rsplit(".")[-2]
        self.name = self.file\
                    .replace(self.path, "")\
                    .replace(".lyr", "")\
                    .replace(self.suffix, "")

    def draw(self):
        '''Draw lyrics on user's screen'''
        maxlen = len(str(len(self.content)))
        print("[[ %s ]]"%self.name)
        for i,line in enumerate(self.content):
            print("%i  %s"%(i+1, line), end="")

    def play(self):
        '''View lyrics'''
        with open(self.file, "r") as f:
            self.content = f.readlines()
        #os.system("cls")
        self.draw()
        input("[[ Press enter to quit ... ]]")

def main(directory):
    # Get lyric files from directory
    lyric_files = []
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if file.endswith(".lyr"):
            lyric_files.append(Lyrics(directory + file))

    # Create variable for showing messages to user
    msg = ""

    # Main loop
    while True:

        # Print lyric files
        #os.system("cls")
        for i, file in enumerate(lyric_files):
            print("%i :: %s"%(i+1, file.name))

        # Handle input
        cmd = input("%s>"%msg)
        if cmd == "bye":
            break
        try:
            lyric_files[int(cmd)-1].play()
            msg = ""
        except ValueError:
            msg = "ValueError: Input must be an integer\n"
        except IndexError:
            msg = "IndexError: Integer must be between 1 and %i\n"%len(lyric_files)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main("E:\\documents\\lyrics\\")
```

---

Files in `E:\documents\lyrics\` are named with following format:

```
Artist - Song.format.lyr`
```

For example:

```
E:\documents\lyrics\Adele - Set Fire to the Rain.mp3.lyr
```

---

When I open the program, it lists all the files as it's supposed to, asking me for an input after:

```
1 :: Adele - Set Fire to the Rain
2 :: Eminem - Not Afraid
3 :: Nicki Minaj - Starships
>
```

When I open up lyrics for `Set Fire to the Rain` with index `1`, they open up just perfectly. However, when I try to open lyrics for `Not Afraid`, I can see around 50 lines of the lyrics on the output, when the lyric file is actually around 120 lines long. It then asks me for an input from the `main()` function with `ValueError` like so:

```
1  first_line_in_lyrics
2  second_line_in_lyrics
i  ...
42 fourty_second_line_in_lyrics
43 fourty_third_line_in_lyrics
1 :: Adele - Set Fire to the Rain
2 :: Eminem - Not Afraid
3 :: Nicki Minaj - Starships
ValueError: Input must be an integer
>
```

The files are pretty much identical to each other (well of course the lyrics are different). The program works just fine on IDLE, but not on python command line.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `except` statements?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Still the same, they don't affect the program. If an error would raise, the lyrics would never get printed in the first place. Now they do get printed, but they just flash on the cmd screen and then the song list reappears.

Comment: What about that `print("\n" * 500)` line? Isn't that why the song list disappears- because it's gone sliding off the screen? What happens when you remove it?

Comment: `get_lyric_files()` returns `None` in the code you provided above. Are you sure you haven't left anything out?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, the song list is meant to disappear with that, and the lyrics' should get then printed. However, the lyrics only flash and the song list reappears (as if `print("\n" * 500)` was called again and the songs re-printed)

Comment: @JoelCornett I've probably accidentally deleted it when copying the code to here, it did return `lyric_files` in my original code. Edited the main post now

Comment: @Hpa: Well, there are two places in the code that do `print("\n" * 500)`. I'm willing to bet that when the lyrics "disappear", it was due to one of those two statements. Try replacing them with `print("AAA")` and `print("BBB")`, and you can both confirm that that's the problem and know which of the lines it is reaching that causes it to disappear.

Comment: In `Lyrics`, you do `read_content()` twice, once in `__init__()`, and once in `play()`. Why is that?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Yes, that seems to be the problem, but I can't understand why... I'll edit the main post in a second.

Comment: @JoelCornett When I init the `Lyrics` object, I want to save current lyrics inside the file to `self.content` list. Also when I play, I want to read the new lyrics every time just incase someone has edited the file by hand.

Comment: Instead of using `print('\n'*500)` to clear your screen, `import os` and use `os.system('clear')` as it's likely to have more predictable results.

Comment: Rewrote the question with some additional information, such as `ValueError` actually raising, but some of the lyrics still getting printed.

Comment: What *exactly* was the last line printed for "Not Afraid"? Was it `I promise to never go back on that promise, in fact`? And what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Oh, and what platform are you on? (Windows, Linux, OS X, etc.) Which version? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem seems pretty weird, but not impossible. Here's what we got at the moment:

1. Since the file does open and some of it gets printed out, the problem MUST be in the printing of the file.
2. I triple checked your code, and the problem is NOT in your `draw()` method.
3. Since the problem only occurs with some files and not with others, the problem is probably in the files themselves.
4. Since the problem only occurs with python command line and not with IDLE: the problem has to be in printing some content of some of the files, which can be printed in IDLE but not in python command line.

If you are CERTAIN that your draw function looks EXACTLY like this (took me a while to figure out the `maxlen` thing):

```
def draw(self):
    '''Draw lyrics on user's screen'''
    maxlen = len(str(len(self.content)))
    print("[[ %s ]]"%self.name)
    for i,line in enumerate(self.content):
        print("%i  %s"%(i+1, line), end="")
```

We're only left with the fact that there's something wrong with `self.content` and/or the file content itself.

Simply put: I'm 99% sure there are some characters in your file which can be printed by IDLE but not by python command line. Such characters could be anything: `%`, `'`, `"`, `´`, `|`, `#`, or even some invisible characters which you can't see without scrolling through them with your arrow keys.

If you could post the content of your lyrics, I could try helping more. Especially the lines which get printed last, and the first lines which don't get printed at all.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem was with `'` letter, such as `I'm` and those lines didn't get printed! I fixed the problem by using `.replace("'", "´")`

Answer (score 0):

You say you've coded a program that:

> It reads the lyrics from .lyr file and prints them out to me

But my reading of your program:

```
def get_lyric_files(path):
    lyric_files = []
    for lyrics in os.listdir(path):
        if lyrics[:-4].split(".")[-1] in ("wav", "mp3"):
            lyric_files .append(Lyrics(path + lyrics))
    return lyric_files
```

Looks like your getting the lyrics out of .mp3 and .wav files. Some mp3 files contain lyrics tags but your not parsing them. Maybe you intended:

```
lyric_files .append(Lyrics(path + lyrics + '.lyr'))
```

#### Start Edit

I now see I misread this line:

```
if lyrics[:-4].split(".")[-1] in ("wav", "mp3"):
```

I thought it was:

```
if lyrics[-4:].split(".")[-1] in ("wav", "mp3"):
```

This code matches `*.mp3.???`. If you're only looking for .lyr files, why not:

```
if lyrics[-8:] in (".wav.lyr", ".mp3.lyr"):
```

#### Edit 2

Also, this is not good:

```
try:
    lyrics[int(cmd)-1].play()
except ValueError:
    pass
except IndexError:
    pass
```

Do you really mean to catch and ignore ValueError and IndexError in .play()? Instead:

```
try:
    lyric = lyrics[int(cmd)-1]
except ValueError:
    print 'You must enter a number'
except IndexError:
    print 'You must enter a number between 1 and', len(lyrics)
else:
    lyric.play()
```

This might help you find your problem if it's in play because the `try` will not be masking any errors.

#### End Edit

Else if you want read lyrics from an .mp3 file you could use a library like mutagen

```
import mutagen, mutagen.mp3, mutagen.easyid3

# . . .

mp3Tags = mutagen.mp3.MP3(mp3FileName)
lyricFrame = mp3Tags.get("USLT::'eng'")
if lyricFrame:
    lyricText = lyricFrame.text
    lyrics = lyricText.split('\n')
```

Comment: The file name is mentioned in the main post, it's fe. `Eminem - Not Afraid.mp3.lyr`. My code first gets rid of `.lyr` with `lyrics[:-4]` and then it checks if the remaining suffix is `in ("mp3", "wav")`

Comment: Thanks I see that now. See edit in my post for a suggestion (though not a fix for your problem).

Comment: Added second edit with improvement to try / except.

Comment: These are both good tips and I was going to apply the error messages later on anyways, but neither one of them fixed my problem, since the error never raises... :/

Comment: I have now rewrote the question, see if it helps at all.

Comment: It helps some. But where are you printing `msg`? You left that line out.

Comment: I didn't, it's there with input. `cmd = input("%s>"%msg)`

Comment: Missed that. Thanks. Here's what I think is going on. You didn't fully take my advice re `try`. So you're still calling `.play()` from within your `try` block. Play is throwing a `ValueError`, apparently within `draw()`'s `for` loop. I'm wondering if it's Unicode conversion related (doesn't exactly fit, but I can't think of anything else). You'll get more information (maybe enough to solve your problem) if you call `play` outside the `try` block.